# Cannot unmount or resize partitions

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, gparted

I cannot unmount or resize the /dev/sda1 partition. The screenshot is attached. I just want to free up a couple hundred gigs to be able to install windows on so I have a dual boot. I was able to swapoff the extended, but now I still cannot unmount the main ext4 partition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/sda1` is your root partition, which indeed can not be unmounted while Ubuntu is running off of it, because this is where the operating system is.

What I usually do in such cases is to boot from a live CD (my favorite is systemrescuecd) and then resize the partition while it is not active.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I didn't think of this before but this seems to be working, just taking a while

Comment: if size is fixed (in systemrescuecd you have no memory to increase or reduce size) try to copy current sda and paste it to create new sda in free memory. Then delete previosly sda (ext4 with directory 'y') and after reboot set grub like here said http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/comp/196